# What is the cardinality of intervals in space, and what is the cardinality of intervals in spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, universe, mathematics, geometry

The interval $|(0, 1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$. I naively thought that one could treat intervals in space in kind, i.e., that the cardinality of any interval in space has the cardinality of the continuum. You'll likely immediately find my use of the word "cardinality," a set-theoretic concept, to talk about the physical universe objectionable. What do I even mean by the cardinality of an interval in space? After all, space is not a set. Well, I suppose I have an intuition that any interval in space is infinitely divisible into smaller measures of space, which are themselves infinitely divisible.

It transpires I wasn't all wrong. $|(a, b)| = |\mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}^{n}|$ where $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Euclidean space. But physical space and spacetime are, of course, not Euclidean. Thanks Einstein.

My question is therefore as follows: even if space and spacetime are not Euclidean, do they not still have $|\mathbb{R}|$ cardinality, where the "cardinality" of space refers to measures of space? Of course, there is no way to prove the "cardinality" of physical space, but do people here reckon it a justifiable assumption that $|$space$| = |\mathbb{R}|$ and moreover that $|(a, b)| = |\mathbb{R}|$, where $a$ is one point in space, and $b$ another point in space?

Comment: What experiment could elucidate this?

Comment: Cardinality is a property of the underlying set and has nothing to do with any additional structure imposed on it.

Comment: It might help people answer your question if you explain what you think the stakes of spacetime having this or that cardinality would be. As MPW says, knowing the cardinality of a set tells us almost nothing about its structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any connected Hausdorff manifold has cardinality equal to the cardinality of ${\mathbb R}$.

There are easy counterexamples if you drop "connected" or "Hausdorff".  Let $\kappa$ be some arbitrarily large cardinal.  Then the (disconnected) disjoint union of $\kappa$ copies of ${\mathbb R}$ has cardinality $\kappa$.   So does the (non-Hausdorff) pushout of $\kappa$ copies of ${\mathbb R}$ over your favorite nonempty open set $U\neq {\mathbb R}$.

So whether spacetime must have the cardinality of ${\mathbb R}$ depends entirely on what assumptions you make about spacetime.  I think that most physicists either explicitly or implicitly assume that spacetime is both connected and Hausdorff.

Comment: Obviously in the definition of "manifold" you include locally homeomorphic to $R^n$. Am I right?

Comment: @ValterMoretti :  Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I could hope that most physicists understand that "connected and Hausdorff" refers to the models we use, and that actual physical space isn't a mathematical object.

Comment: @JohnDoty:  Clearly physical space is clearly not identical to the models we use, but that seems to leave open the question of whether it's a mathematical object.   In any event, I took the question to be about the models.

Comment: Hausdorff property is quite physical actually! It is the same as saying that the measure instrument are finitely precise but we can however distinguish a point from another point, even if our precision is not infinite. Physical measure instruments define the neighbourhoods of a Hausdorff topology. Hausdorff property is a physical property of space and time, according to our present knowledge.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Interesting. Do you know a good citation for the viewpoint that the Hausdorff property is a physical property of spacetime?

Comment: I do not know, it seems to me quite obvious. I wrote it in my recent book on Analytical Mechanics (Springer 2023) for instance....

Comment: @ValterMoretti I understand if you don't want to make any of the text of such a recent publication available publicly, but I'd love to see the exact passage and wording in which you say it.

Comment: @ValterMoretti :  It's not entirely clear to me why you consider this an argument for spacetime being Hausdorff, as opposed to $T1$.  (Either way, it's a very nice observation.)

Comment: Yes, the physical distinction between T1 and T2 would deserve a better discussion…

Comment: @Andres There is a discussion on p 29 of my last book. As pointed out by WillO, I should improve that argument to distinguish between T1 and T2...

Comment: @Andres Here is the passage."The topological structure allows in particular (but not only) to make sense of the 
ideas of “spatial and temporal proximity”. Requiring that the topology is Hausdorff 
has a profound physical motivation. Because of the experimental errors made by 
measuring instruments, any spacetime determination is only approximatively accurate. We may locate an event only with a certain approximation. In mathematical 
terms, we may only detect neighbourhoods of events and not the events themselves. "

Comment: "These neighbourhoods are determined by the imprecisions, as small as we like 
but non-zero, of the instruments that measure space and time.  That the spacetime 
topology is Hausdorff means that we can always distinguish two events so long as 
the measurements are sufficiently precise, even if not infinitely precise."

Comment: Valter Moretti.  Analytical Mechanics
Classical, Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics, Stability Theory, Special Relativity. Springer 2023 https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-27612-5

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you very much for providing these.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Given any collection of real physical instruments, there will always be events that are distinguishable in a mathematical model, but not in reality. So, your mathematics fails to capture reality: it is an idealization.

Comment: @johnDoty :  why are you holding fixed the collection of instruments?  Doesn't that change over time --- sometimes in direct response to a desire to distinguish that which was peviously indistinguishable?

Comment: @WillO Because I can't acquire an instrument with arbitrary precision. I'm limited to things that actually exist. Even if I can get a better instrument in the future, I can't arbitrarily specify what precision it will deliver.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Another problem with your model is that we can only distinguish points with limited confidence. Sometimes, the object is outside the 90% confidence box.

Answer (score 8):

Physics adopts models. Models of spacetime as a continuum are commonly adopted. But such an assumption is built in to the model, so the model cannot itself tell you whether the assumption was justified. The model is deemed to be adequate when its testable predictions agree with what is found empirically, and when it is an elegant model. But we really don't know the answer to your question, when it comes to actual space and time, because we don't have a way of testing it.

Sometimes attempts to treat spacetime in a quantum physics offer something intermediate between continuous and discrete. Try looking up "loop quantum gravity" and similar. You can have a discrete set of eigenstates, but a continuum of superpositions of those states. Maybe spacetime has that kind of nature. We don't know.